# Im trying to create a Pandas DataFrame so that each city corresponds to its country

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I want the new dataframe to contain 4 columns(Country, City, ImrByCountry, PopulationByCity) instead of current 3(Country, IMRperCountry, PopulationByCountry)

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9A0.png)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {}

for country in root.findall("country"):
    country_name = country[0].text
    imr = country.findtext('infant_mortality')
    population = country.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")

    cities_in_country = {}

    for city in country.findall("city"):
        city_name = city[0].text
        city_population = city.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")
        cities_in_country[city_name] = city_population

    data[country_name] = {
        'IMR': imr,
        'Population': population,
        'City': cities_in_country
    }
```

I have tried to create a dataframe from the given dictionary but it didnt work out for me
[XML source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDwJo.png)

Comment: `it didnt work out for me` - Can you add example of dictionary to question and your expected ouput?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your XML document, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create list of dictionaries by `append` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = []

for country in root.findall("country"):
    country_name = country[0].text
    imr = country.findtext('infant_mortality')
    population = country.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")

    for city in country.findall("city"):
        city_name = city[0].text
        city_population = city.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")

        d = {
            'Country': country_name,
            'City':city_name,
            'ImrByCountry': imr,
            'PopulationByCity': city_population
        }
        L.append(d)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Another idea is create list of tuples:

```
L = []

for country in root.findall("country"):
    country_name = country[0].text
    imr = country.findtext('infant_mortality')
    population = country.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")

    cities_in_country = {}

    for city in country.findall("city"):
        city_name = city[0].text
        city_population = city.findtext("./population[@year='2011']")
        cities_in_country[city_name] = city_population

        tup = (country_name,city_name,imr,city_population)
        L.append(tup)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Country','City','ImrByCountry','PopulationByCity'])
```